# Spectral Radius of a Block Matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I have real matrix $P$ obtained from numerical solution (FEM) of a physical problem, as
\begin{equation}
P=P_1+P_2=
\begin{bmatrix}
A_{2n \times 2n}&B_{2n \times n}\\C_{n \times 2n}&D_{n \times n}
\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
P_1=
\begin{bmatrix}
A_{2n \times 2n}&0\\0&0
\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
P_2=
\begin{bmatrix}
0&B_{2n \times n}\\C_{n \times 2n}&D_{n \times n}
\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}
In which $A$ and $D$ are symmetric and positive semi-definite. As I know, there are only some inequality relations between spectral radius of $P$, $\rho(P)$, and that of $P_1$ and $P_2$. However, my numerical studies show that under some certain conditions $\rho(P)=\rho(P_1)$. From physical point of view, these result makes plenty of sense under those conditions; however, I need a mathematical proof for it. Is there any condition under which $\rho(P)$ is equal to $\rho(P_1)$?

By the way, in those cases $\rho(P_2)$ and norm of its blocks are not small and negligible.